# Одинаковый вид кнопки в разных браузерах

Tags: css3, html, css

Помогите отредактировать кнопку. Есть кнопка:

```
<button id="but_hei">
<p>
    <img src="knopka.jpg"/>knopka
</p>
</button>
```

и каскадная таблица стилей для неё:

```
<style type="text/css">
    button p
    {
        line-height:50px;
    }
    button img
    {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
    }
    #but_hei
    {
        height:50px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтоб она во всех браузерах выглядела одинаково?

Comment: [button][1]


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Кроссбраузерный button](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/verstka-form/crossbrowser-button.html).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
<input type="image" src="knopka.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую юзать YUI 3.x. И это решено и много других ++